# Spring boot hibernate problem posting json object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, entity

I have a problem related to POST a JSON object to persist the data in an Spring boot application.

The entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extended_company_info")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ExtendedCompanyInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    private String phone;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "extendedCompanyInfo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<AddressInfo> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Company company;

    //… getters setters

}
```

The table looks like this: **extended_company_info (id, city, url, phone)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “address_info")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class AddressInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = “address”, nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = “address_type", nullable = false)
    private AddressType addressType;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="extended_company_info_id")
    @NotNull
    private ExtendedCompanyInfo extendedCompanyInfo;

    //… getters setters

}
```

Table looks like this: **address_info (id, address, address_type, extended_company_info_id)**

```
public enum AddressType {
    ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3
}
```

The JSON object that I POST look like this:

```
{
    “city”: “city”,
    “url”: “http://www.url.com”,
    “phone”: “123456789”,
    “addresses”: [{
        “address”: “address abcd”,
        “addressType": “ADDRESS1”
    }],
    "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": “Company name“,
        "shortName": “Company shortname“,
        "customerNumber": "1234"
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Bad Request: Validation failed for classes [package.AddressInfo] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath= extendedCompanyInfo, rootBeanClass=class package.AddressInfo, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
```

In what way should I structure extendedCompanyInfo in the JSON object?

What am I missing?

Comment: extendedCompanyInfo is annotated with @NotNull. Remove it and test again.

Comment: why do you have NotNull annotations on some objects when you post JSON object without those objects with NotNull annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commentators mention above:
You're stating that extendedCompanyInfo cannot be null and that the Many-one relationship between AddressInfo and ExtendedCompanyInfo is not optional.

Your json representation that you're posting does not include the extendedCompanyInfo node and therefore is failing your validation.

Either include the extendedCompanyInfo in the JSON post or remove the @NotNull and optional = false annotations.

Comment: If I remove the `@NotNull` and `optional = false` annotations form extendedCompanyInfo it works but then the column `extended_company_info_id` in `address_info` table is null which is correct. But I want the `id` to `extendedCompanyInfo` in`extended_company_info_id` column. How can I achieve this in the same JSON object?